# Why is find -delete faster than rm -rf?

Tags: linux, rm

Why is `find ... -delete` so much faster than `rm -rf` ?  Specifically,

To clarify:  I'm specifically asking: Why is `find ./x -type d -delete && rm -rf x` so much faster than `rm -rf x/`?

#### Background

There have been a few people who use similar mechanisms, like rsync.

- There are several posts on why `rm -rf` is slow.  For example, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106133/why-is-rm-slow is probably one of the most focused ones.
- Specifically, I've found `cd dir-to-delete && find . -type d -delete` followed by `rm -rf dir-to-delete` is extremely fast,  even on large directories.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/ is probably  a better place to ask this question.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be faster? It's invoking the `unlink()` syscall **instead of starting a whole different program**.

Comment: `find` has some optimizations in regard to walking directories. Especially it looks at the link count to see if a dir is empty. I don't know if `rm` does not contain those. You could `strace -c ...`both to get a count of systemcalls and have a look

Comment: are you running rm on a single top level directory or on a larger list (or even worse multiple times)?

Comment: your "specifically" command - are there any files in the directory tree or only empty dirs?

Answer (score 2):

`rm -f` isn't slow, but if you run it many files and you fire up a separate process per each `rm`, then it will be slow, because starting a process will cost you about 2ms on modern processor, and many files can be deleted in that time if you instead delete in batches, which is what find's `-delete` does. Alternatively, you can use `xargs` to run `rm` with a batch to pretty much the same effect.

Comment: "Pretty much the same effect"? We're talking whole milliseconds to spawn `/bin/rm` even once.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy 2ms is nothing if you can pass hundreds of files to that `rm` invocation.

Comment: Depends on your baseline. If it's tmpfs, 2ms is enough time for a whole lot of `unlink()`s, making the performance difference as a percentage significant. :)

Comment: Could you recast your answer as `rm -f is slower because it doesnt delete in batches` ?  if thats your answer, then i think that would be a good summary.

Comment: @jayunit100, ...the proposed recasting *isn't correct*. Deleting in batches has nothing to do with it, except inasmuch as passing a large number of arguments to a single `rm -f` call allows the startup times for `/bin/rm` to be amortized over all the files at hand.

Comment: @jayunit100 `rm` is quite eager to delete in batches, but if you do `find ... -exec rm -f {} \;` you're only passing one file. You either need `find ... -exec rm -f {} +` or `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f ` to give it a batch and thereby minimize the number of invocations.

Comment: FYI -- OP's edits to the question have made both my answer and probably this one as well no longer relevant.